# Google AdMob error after entering personal AdsId

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, admob

upuntill the use of test ids and data for using admob in my flutter app was perfectly fine. Then I used personal ID from admob and I started getting erros.

LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Publisher data not found. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#9, responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})

Please note I also have added test device, and am using below code

```
 await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
 await MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
    RequestConfiguration(
      testDeviceIds: <String>['Oppo'],
    ),
```